# Animated modal view transition in popover

Tags: ios

I am having a problem with animated modal transitions in a popover. For some reason when I have the transition set to be animated, the popover resizes horizontally. When I don't have it animated, there is no resize. Picture 1 is with animation, pic 2 is without.

The code where I'm creating the transition is:

```
StoreDetailViewController *sdvc = [[StoreDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StoreDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

sdvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
sdvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
sdvc.modalInPopover = YES;

sdvc.play = playData;
sdvc.st = self;
sdvc.indoors = indoors;

[parent presentModalViewController:sdvc animated:YES];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtcEb.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioY0R.png

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I've made sure that both the parent popover view and the view that I'm changing to are both the same size. I just have no clue what is causing this to only happen when I have the transition set to be animated.

Comment: Have you overridden `-contentSizeForViewInPopover`?